# Synchronize two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, synchronization, data-synchronization

I am creating two websites. The thing common about both websites is the company tables.
What I want to do is this: If one company table is updated, the other company table is also updated accordingly.

Both databases are on the same server.

What would be the best way to do this? (Doing this via code is not possible, due to the type of framework I am using.)

I would prefer a solution at the database level.

Comment: Can you make one table as a view on the other?

Comment: [Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) are almost certainly the way to go for this.  You should only have one version of your data; if you want to see different transformations of that data, use views.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can join tables across two different databases, so maybe you can get away with a single table. Otherwise, triggers would be useful to keep two tables in sync.